# How to select the most important features, categorical & numerical data

Tags: r, k-nearest-neighbour, caret

I need to find out which factors are relevant when predicting low birth weight. My model looks like this:

```
low_bw_knn = train(low ~ ., method = "knn", data = trn_low_bw,
                   trControl = trainControl(method = 'cv', number = 5))
```

I have already plotted a confusion matrix, but this only works with numeric values.

```
correlationMatrix <- cor(low_birth_weight[,c(3,4,5,11)])
print(correlationMatrix)
```

Is there a way to find out which factors are most relevant, (besides editing and trying different models) with KNN? I'm not allowed to use other things like randomforest.

The data looks like this:

```
dput(head(low_birth_weight))
structure(list(id = c(4L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 15L, 16L), low = c("yes", 
"yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes"), bwt = c(709L, 1021L, 1135L, 
1330L, 1474L, 1588L), age = c(28, 29, 34, 25, 25, 27), lwt = c(120, 
130, 187, 105, 85, 150), race = c("other", "white", "black", 
"other", "other", "other"), smoke = c("yes", "no", "yes", "no", 
"no", "no"), ptl = c("one", "none", "none", "one", "none", "none"
), ht = c("no", "no", "yes", "yes", "no", "no"), ui = c("yes", 
"yes", "no", "no", "yes", "no"), ftv = c(0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L)), .Names = c("id", "low", "bwt", "age", "lwt", "race", "smoke", 
"ptl", "ht", "ui", "ftv"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```